# Can someone please help me DRY my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, dry

My code pretty repetitive and I lose some functionality when I try to `DRY*` it myself. I'm new to this so any advise is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById('spe').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var kitten = document.getElementById('spe').value;
  kitten = kitten.toLowerCase();
  if (kitten.search('qwe') !== -1) {
    alert('potential watchlist');
  } 
  if (kitten.search('americredit') !== -1) {
    alert('potential watchlist');
  }
  if (kitten.search('bay view') !== -1) {
    alert('potential watchlist');
  }
  if (kitten.search('nationwide equ') !== -1) {
    alert('potential watchlist');
  }
  if (kitten.search('the moss ') !== -1) {
    alert('potential watchlist');
  }
  if (kitten.search('kurt gei') !== -1) {
    alert('potential watchlist');
  }
  if (kitten.search('haier') !== -1) {
    alert('potential watchlist');
  }
  if (kitten.search('objekts') !== -1) {
    alert('potential watchlist');
  }
  document.getElementById('spe').value = kitten;
},false);
```

`* DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself`

Comment: Put the strings to search for in an array, then use a loop...

Comment: `if (/americredit|bay view|haier|kurt gei|nationwide equ|objekts|qwe|the moss/.test(kitten) { alert("Potential watchlist") }`